# String conversion when reading file in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working with VBA which I am not used to. I am making a script that reads some data from txt-files and then makes a graph out of it. The script reads the txt-files collects the data and inputs it into an excel-workbook. Then makes graphs of these values.
One value is supposed to be multiplied by a factor of ten. However when reading the values and trying to convert them to doubles I stumble upon lots of problems.

This is what the file looks like. And the second column is what is of interest here.

```
444.267 70.26   332.562 0.692   2   1   0   157.48
444.933 70.26   342.562 0.692   2   1   0   157.48
446.533 72.88   342.562 0.692   2   1   0   157.48
462.933 75.5    342.562 0.692   2   1   0   157.48
468.667 75.5    331.75  0.692   2   1   0   157.48
479.333 75.5    331.75  0.692   2   12  0   157.48
479.733 75.5    331.75  0.692   2   11  0   157.48
480.133 75.5    331.75  0.692   2   1   0   157.48
539.467 75.5    331.75  0.692   2   12  0   157.48
```

Below I've attached some code. I've changed it somewhat for debugging purposes.

```
For tmp1 = 1 To 70
        'While Not EOF(FileNum)
            Dim DataLine_Array() As String
            Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
            DataLine_Array = Split(DataLine, vbTab)

            Cells(i, 1) = DataLine_Array(0)
            Cells(i, 2) = DataLine_Array(1)
            Cells(i, 3) = DataLine_Array(2)
            Cells(i, 4) = DataLine_Array(3)
            Cells(i, 5) = DataLine_Array(4)
            Cells(i, 6) = DataLine_Array(5)
            Cells(i, 7) = DataLine_Array(6)
            Cells(i, 8) = DataLine_Array(7)
            On Error GoTo ErrLabel:
            Dim Tmp_Double As Double
            Tmp_Double = DataLine_Array(3)
            Cells(i, 10) = (Tmp_Double)

            'Here it goes wrong
            Cells(i, 9) = DataLine_Array(1) / 10
            Dim Test_test As String
            Dim test_test2 As Double
            Test_test = DataLine_Array(1) / 10
            test_test2 = DataLine_Array(1)

            'Output
            Debug.Print 'start'
            Debug.Print DataLine_Array(1)
            Debug.Print Test_test
            Debug.Print VarType(Test_test)
            Debug.Print test_test2
            Debug.Print VarType(test_test2)

ErrLabel:
            Resume Next
            i = i + 1
        Next tmp1
```

And this is what is being outputted.

```
70.26
702,6
 8 
 7026 
 5 

72.88
728,8
 8 
 7288 
 5 

75.5
75,5
 8 
 755 
 5 

75.5
75,5
 8 
 755 
 5
```

As you can see, the output is correct when just printing the line the output is correct.
When storing it as a string however the dot changes to a comma and switch place depending on how many decimals there is. I am in European country where comma is  being used instead of dot as decimal separator. But this shouldn't effect a string in my mind.
When trying to store the value as a double, the decimals completely disappear.

The goal is to read the second column of the file as it is and multiply it with ten. This is hard as long as I don't read the values on consistent manner however.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Mange_Man

My suggestion would be to start by taking your file data and putting it into an Excel worksheet. If the VBA is not working within Excel, then it won't work with file I/O either.

Try pasting your array into excel and run the macro I have below.

If your column "I" does not have the values multiplied by 10 then my guess is it is an issue with your regional settings of Excel (European).

Otherwise it might have to do with your computer itself and how it interacts with file I/O with Excel and the European regional settings. Anyways try it first in excel as a start..

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim arr() As Double

Range("A1:A9").Select 'Select your nine rows

'Set delimiter if necessary
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

i = 8
ReDim arr(i)

For n = 0 To i
    arr(n) = Range("B" & n + 1).value * 10 'Multiply values by 10
Next n

For n = 0 To i
    Range("I" & n + 1).value = arr(n) 'Set values in Column "I"
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved it in a similar fashion to this :)